# Bootstrap grid inside asp.net repeater control

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I'm using asp.net web form's. I have a grid with  8 columns. I want to make this grid responsive. So I'm trying to  convert it in to a repeater control. I can put it as table and  can add bootstrap  css to it. But   table doesn't break  down to  columns  in smaller screen. So i want to add a bootstrap grid  inside  the repeater  control.  Any body provide me  sample ui code.

```html
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 table table-bordered">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpActions" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="sqlActions">
                    <HeaderTemplate> 
                        <div class="row table-bordered">
                                 <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-5 ">
                                Edit
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5">
                                 DateCreated
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5">
                                 ActionTypeID
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-5">
                                 AddedByUser
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5">
                                 ContactID
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-5">
                                 Notes
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-5">
                                 FollowUp
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-5">
                                 FollowUp
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                        <div class="row table-bordered ">
                            <div class="col-md-1 border col-sm-5">Edit</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 border col-sm-5">
                            <asp:Label                                                                                 ID="LabelDateCreated" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("DateCreated") %>'>
                            </asp:Label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList10" runat="server"                                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1a"                                                          DataTextField="ActionType"                                                              DataValueField="ActionTypeID" SelectedValue='<%#                                        Bind("ActionTypeID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="">
                                 </asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1a"                                              runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$                                                    ConnectionStrings:WebCRMProCS %>"                                                     SelectCommand="SELECT [ActionTypeID],                                                   [ActionType] FROM [tblActionTypes] ORDER BY                                             [ActionType]">
                                         </asp:SqlDataSource>
                              </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-5"> 
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelUser" runat="server" Text='<%#                                          Bind("AddedByUser") %>'>
                            </asp:Label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5"> 
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList13" 
                                 runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1e"                                          DataTextField="ContactFullName" 
                                 DataValueField="ContactID" SelectedValue='<%#                                          Bind("ContactID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="">
                            </asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1e"
                        runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$                                                    ConnectionStrings:WebCRMProCS %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [ContactID], 
                        isnull([ContactFullName], email) as ContactFullName 
                        FROM [tblContacts] WHERE ([CompanyID] = @CompanyID) 
                        ORDER BY [ContactFullName]">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter 
                                ControlID="detailCompany" Name="CompanyID"                                            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource></div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-5">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#                                         Bind("Notes") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-5">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFollowup" runat="server" Checked='<%#                            Bind("FollowUp") %>' /></div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-5">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1a" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("DateFollowUp", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: There is no difference using Bootstrap Grid inside or outsite a Repeater. It just repeats a certain code block.

Comment: Please check my html code. because grid is not working properly .

Comment: When you say you want to make the table responsive... what do you want it to do at the `sm` breakpoint?

Comment: want to break in to 2 columns in sm